# How can an experimental physicist create a free electron gas in air?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, electrons, gas, experimental-technique

Suppose an experimental physicist has to create a free electron gas in a test chamber filled with air or any gas. They can do this with arcing, photoelectric effect, or [others](https://qr.ae/pvLX5z). What would be the best method or technique to get electrons to form a gas-like state where the electrons can be moving in more or less random directions?

Are there any examples of this being done by researchers/experimentalists anywhere?

Comment: So not a plasma, only electrons?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. Only electrons. @JonCuster

Comment: If you just want a free electron gas, the space charge cloud around the cathode of a vacuum tube qualifies.

Comment: What's the point of the gif embedded in the question?

Comment: @hft It is to show visually what I am talking about: an "electron gas".

Comment: @JohnDoty Maybe you can give a more detailed description of what you are talking about? I would be happy to consider it as a possible answer to my question.

Comment: How does that gif show visually an "electron gas"? It is just an animation of a bunch of blue and red dots in a box. Electrons are not distinguishable (the dots clearly are). Electrons are point particle, the dots' sizes are a large fraction of the box size. The gif is not relevant, get rid of it.

Comment: @hft I think you are taking things too literally. I meant that gif to be an illustration, not anything objective. You are right, they are point particles and are not distinguishable. However, I could not find anything close to an electron gas on the web as a gif. So I found closest thing I could find.

Comment: I'm not taking it literally, I'm telling you it is distracting from your actual question. It is like a salutation or a sign off, it should be removed.

Comment: @hft Like all physics problems, it involves a model. You're promoting a different model. Is your model relevant to the question? The classical statistical mechanics of particles does a good job of capturing what happens in a vacuum tube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you shoot a beam of electrons into a volume of *air*, the free electrons immediately start knocking other electrons off of the gas molecules they are traveling through and you get a mix of electrons and positive ions. Then you begin generating new chemical compounds out of the excited gas atoms, especially ozone.

If you want a cloud of electrons *only*, you cannot form that cloud in *air*. It must be done in a vacuum.

Note that the original SLAC electron beamline generated bunches of very fast-moving electrons. The physicists and engineers had to account for the gas-like behavior of the electron bunches as they traveled down the beamline. Fortunately, from the electron's viewpoint they spent almost no time traversing the line from end to end which hence furnished not much opportunity for the electrons to start acting like a gas.